# Highchart - Angular 9: How to export all charts into single pdf?

Tags: highcharts, angular9

I am configuring Highchart in my application and exporting individual chart by using "exporting" API (importing ExportingModule) successfully.
But not able to find any way to export all the charts in the page on single click (say, exportAll button on top of the page)
I've already imported following highchart modules in my application:

```
import ExportingModule from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import DownloadingModule from 'highcharts/modules/export-data.js';

ExportingModule(Highcharts);
DownloadingModule(Highcharts);
```

Rendering charts by passing id and chart options:

```
Highcharts.chart(this.chartId, this.optiondata)
```

Is there a way/API to export all charts in single pdf?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question you can find in the Highcharts FAQ.

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#can-i-export-multiple-charts-to-the-same-image-or-pdf

Comment: I saw that jQuery workaround. Was just curious if we have any alternative in angular

Comment: @SatAj, unfortunately, there is no official alternative in Angular environment from Highcharts site. You can report this idea on Highcharts-Angular repo: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues